Clear target innerHTML using HTMX
I have a Boostrap modal that I want to reuse.  I pop it up with a different VendorId each time.  I want to be able to clear the modal body before the HTMX AJAX (hx-get) is complete, so the old HTML from the previous Vendor ID does not show during the HTMX request.
I tried messing with hx-indicator and classes to show/hide during the request, but only the indicator and the calling element have the .htmx-request class applied.
Here is the solution I came up with, but I don't like it.  I have to fall back on JavaScript. See hx-on:htmx:before-request below.  Is there any clever way to do this with HTMX?
<a class="dropdown-item"
href="#"
data-toggle="modal"
data-target="#edit-vendor-modal"
hx-trigger="click"
hx-on:htmx:before-request="document.getElementById('edit-vendor-form-container').innerHTML='';"
hx-get="@Url.Action("Edit", "Vendors", new { Model.VendorId })"
hx-target="#edit-vendor-form-container"
hx-indicator="#edit-vendor-form-spinner">Edit</a>

I also thought to have the modal cancel or close button clear the Inner HTML, but there is no way to do that in HTMX without adding a /clear route to your server side which is very silly.

From the HTMX docs, part of the whole point of the framework is "update by request" (as in web requests). Regarding your issue, do you really need to clear the dialog content on close? After all, once the dialog is closed, the content is hidden anyway.

I'm reusing the same modal again with a different Vendor ID.  The previous content shows during the htmx-request.

The short answer is no - it's not possible to manipulate the DOM without some extra js, especailly when dealing with 3rd party js widgets like bs modal.  You may consider some alternatives though, like: 1) apply indicator element on the entire modal content to avoid the "flickering" effect caused by the old content. 2) Use inline editing instead of modal if possible (check htmx examples)

Inline edit is a great idea; I will try that for a different use case.
